# Show untitled appendices in PDF index

Tags: pdf, appendices, bookmarks

I'm writting a document with the *report* class, and I'm using untitled appendices.

```
\appendix
\chapter{}
%this is Appendix A
\chapter{}
%this is Appendix B
```

With this method, pdflatex correctly names them as Appendix A and B, both in-text and in the table of contents. All the appendices, and their respective sections/subsections, show up correctly (and automatically) in the TOC.
My problem is that these appendices don't show up in the pdf index (bookmark) links. I've tried using both `hiperref` and `bookmark` packages, but they both present exactly the same behavior.

If I give the appendix a title it than shows up normally in the index, but I want to keep them untitled. Is there way to have untitled appendices show up in the pdf bookmark/index?

I don't want to add them manually, because these appendices also have a lot of sections and subsections, which I want added as well. They all show up automatically in the TOC, so there must be a way for them to show up in the pdf bookmarks as well.

Comment: How about using `\chapter[Appendix~\thechapter]{}`?

Comment: @Werner that solves the bookmark issue, but creates a new one. My table of content now reads: *A Appendix A*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the following code I am getting two (empty) bookmarks:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\appendix
\chapter{}
%this is Appendix A
\chapter{}
%this is Appendix B

\end{document}
```

Note that `hyperref` doesn't add the chapter/section numbers to the bookmarks by default.

Using the `bookmarksnumbered` option as in

```
\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref}
```

will make the letters A, B appear.

Comment: I'm sorry if I was unclear. This does solve my problem. Appendices weren't showing up at all in the bookmarks, and I just wanted them to show up (I don't really care if it shows up as `A` or as `Appendix A`). As I said, this solves it, and they show up as `A` and `B`.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\appendix
\chapter{\texorpdfstring{}{Appendix \Alph{chapter}}}
%this is Appendix A
\chapter{\texorpdfstring{}{Appendix \Alph{chapter}}}
%this is Appendix B

\end{document}
```

It's usually convenient to load the `bookmark` package (after `hyperref`), but it's not required.