# How does one show an empty section?

Tags: sectioning

I was wondering about the inverse of this question:

[Hiding section titles when the section is empty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38775/hiding-section-titles-when-the-section-is-empty)

Instead of hiding empty sections in LaTeX, can one display only empty sections or somehow indicate that a section is empty in the table of contents?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Perhaps [Show untitled appendices in PDF index](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51442) might help

Comment: Thanks! Ms./Mr. Crowley solved this problem, but I'll look at this. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This comes as first idea:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\emphsection}[2]{% emhasizes empty sections
    \ifstrequal{ #2}{ }{\section[empty: #1]{#1} #2}{\section{#1} #2}%
}

\begin{document}
\emphsection{Emptysection}{}
\emphsection{Section 1}{%
This section won't be emphasized
}
\emphsection{Section 2}
Neither this one.
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works, thank you! (Just to clarify for others reading this: Argument #1 = section title, Argument #2 = section text.)

Comment: @AnthonyPulido This works, but there are some costs to making the section text an argument, notably that verbatim won't work any more, it's also slower although that is less important these days.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, I think you're right. I spoke too soon. I tried it on a small bit of text at first, which worked. I then tried it on what I wanted to use it on, text with subsections and long paragraphs. I'm now receiving an error: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].

Comment: @Crowley Would you have any new ideas?

Comment: @AnthonyPulido The second use shouldn't exceed capacity since only first symbol is used as argument #2.

Comment: @Crowley I think the capacity mistake was something I did. I changed what I did back and tried it again yesterday, but, for some reason. It wouldn't work. I tried it again today, and it seems to be working.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think Crowley's section 2 example gives an answer to your objection. I didn't know this before, but maybe you are more familiar with it---it looks like one doesn't receive an error if the second argument isn't specified. Since we know the section isn't empty, using the second argument is optional. So, one can then use the verbatim command with \emphsection.

Comment: @Crowley Anyway, this works great, even with the long text in the document I'm working with. Thanks again!

Comment: @AnthonyPulido you can always omit the `{}` around a tex parameter, so if you omit the `{}` in this case the the argument is the first letter or command of the section, although in most cases that will work OK.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see, so that's how it works! I just tested it, and in this case, it looks like the verbatim environment still works, although it doesn't work when you use the braces, as you said. I'll remember your comment for the future.

Comment: @AnthonyPulido `verbatim` environment or `\verb` command and many others cannot be used in argument.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this would work

\section*{}

This will create a new blank section with the same spacing as a normal section.

Comment: I needed to be able to tell which sections were blank from looking at the table of contents, and so this is not quite what I was looking for, but thank you!